# Bifurcation points in parametric Hammerstein Integral equation

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, integral-operators, nonlinear-eigenvalue

I am a theoretical physicist working on integrable systems, hence I preemptively ask forgiveness for the eventual lack of mathematical rigor.

My question concerns the properties of a particular example of a Hammerstein equation depending non-trivially on a parameter. The specific property I am interested in is the existence of multiple solution branches and bifurcation points. In order to be as clear as possible and establish what I already know, I am going to present some background information, define the branching points and some elementary property and then present the specific case I am dealing with. Then I will pose a few questions that I would like to have an answer to. Also any reference to relevant literature is very much welcome.

#### Background

In the course of my research, I often have to deal with non-linear integral equations of the following type:
\begin{equation} \varepsilon(\theta) = r\cosh\theta - \intop_{\mathbb R} d\theta' \Phi\left(\theta - \theta'\right)\log\left[1+e^{-\varepsilon(\theta')}\right] \;. \tag{1}\end{equation}
In integrable systems literature an equation like (1) is known as Thermodynamic Bethe Ansatz (TBA) equation. The usual way to deal with such equations is to solve them numerically, often by Neumann series method. While this approach is generally efficient and yields sufficient informations, it is sometime desirable to have some degree of analytic control on certain features of TBA equations. In my case the relevant feature is the existence of bifurcation points in the parametric dependence of the solution(s) $\varepsilon^\ast(\theta)$ on the parameter $r$. I will be more concrete below; what I wish to stress here is that the existence of such a point is of physical relevance and any analytic information on it would be precious. This is also due to the fact that in the vicinity of said bifurcation points, usual numerical routines suffer from heavy slowing down, loss of accuracy and overall non-convergence: any analytical foothold would be precious. Similarly, any information concerning the existence and position of bifurcation points, obtainable directly from the properties of the kernel $\Phi$ is of huge importance as it allows to avoid a case by case study and makes contact with the general properties of the underlying physical system -- which are reflected in the kernel $\Phi$.

#### Bifurcation points

Going through some references on integral equations, I realized that equation (1) is an example of a parametric Hammerstein equation on the real line, whose general form is
\begin{equation}
 u(x) = \intop_{\mathbb R} dt K(x,t)\Psi\left(t,u(t);\lambda\right)\;,\qquad x,t\in\mathbb R\;,\quad \lambda\in\mathbb C\;. \tag{2}
\end{equation}
As is the case whenever non-linearity is involved, the equation (2) might display some peculiar behaviour, one of which is the existence of bifurcation points.

> **Bifurcation point** (adapted from [1])
>
> A value $\lambda_c$ is a *bifurcation point* for the equation (2) if $\forall \epsilon>0\;,\; \exists \lambda\in\left(\lambda_c-\epsilon,\lambda_c+\epsilon\right)$ such that there exist two solutions $u(x) = u(x;\lambda)$ and $\tilde{u}(x) = \tilde{u}(x;\lambda)$ satisfying $\left\vert u(x) - \tilde{u}(x)\right\vert<\epsilon$.

Here $\lambda_c\in\mathbb R$, but it should be easy to generalize to the complex plane. In [1], pag. 836, I found these two nice little theorems

> **Theorem 1**
>
> Let $\lambda_c$ be a bifurcation point and $u(x) = u(x;\lambda)$ a solution of (2). Then $\nu = 1$ is a characteristic value of the kernel $L(x,t;\lambda_\ast) = K(x,t)\frac{d}{dy}\Psi(t,y;\lambda_\ast)\Big\vert_{y=u(x;\lambda_\ast)}$.

and

> **Theorem 2**
>
> Let $\nu(\lambda) = 1$ be a characteristic value of the kernel $L(x,t;\lambda) = K(x,t)\frac{d}{dy}\Psi(t,y;\lambda)\Big\vert_{y=u(x;\lambda)}$ defined in the above Theorem and let its multiplicity be equal to $1$. Then the solution(s) $\lambda_\ast$ to the equation $\nu(\lambda) = 1$ is a(are) bifurcation point(s).

Thus the question about the existence of bifurcation points reduces to the analysis of the spectrum of the linearized kernel $L(x,t;\lambda)$. While this is indeed a simplification, one still needs to have control over one solution $u(x;\lambda)$, which is often achievable only at a numerical level.

#### The specific case

In order to make things more concrete let me display the specific equation I am working with:
\begin{equation}
 \varepsilon(\theta) = r\cosh\theta - \intop_{\mathbb R} \frac{d\theta'}{2\pi} \sum_{\sigma,\sigma' = \pm 1}\frac{1}{\cosh\left[\theta - \theta' + \sigma \omega + i \sigma' \gamma\right]}\log\left[1+e^{-\varepsilon(\theta')}\right]\;, \quad \omega\in\mathbb R\;,\quad \gamma\in\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\;. \tag{3}
\end{equation}

Numerical analysis convinces me that there exist a value $r=r_c\in\mathbb R_{>0}$ which has the features of a bifurcation point. More specifically I see the following behaviour for $r\gtrsim r_c$:
\begin{equation}
 \varepsilon(\theta) \underset{r\searrow r_c}{\sim} A(\theta) + B(\theta)\sqrt{r_c-r}+\mathcal O(r_c-r)\;. \tag{4}
\end{equation}
If I insert expression (4) into (3) and compare the dependence on $r$, I obtain the following equations (here $\Phi$ is the kernel of (3))
\begin{equation}
 A(\theta) = r_c \cosh\theta - \intop_{\mathbb R}dt \Phi\left(\theta - \theta'\right) \log\left[1+e^{-A(\theta')}\right]\;, \tag{5}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 B(\theta) = \intop_{\mathbb R}dt \Phi\left(\theta - \theta'\right) \frac{B(\theta')}{1+e^{A(\theta')}}\;. \tag{6}
\end{equation}
This is exactly what I would expect from the Theorems mentioned above: equation (6) is the linearized equation with unit eigenvalue, evaluated on a solution $A(\theta)$ of (3) at the (supposed) bifurcation point $r=r_c$.

#### My questions

After this, admittedly lengthy, introduction, I think I have a reasonable grasp of the general situation. I have however a few questions that I hope you could help me answer (or at least shed some light on). Although I am currently working on the specific example (3), I would be very interested in an answer to the questions below for the more general case (1) -- possibly also an extension to systems of equations of type (1).

1. First of all I would like to have a workable way to determine the existence of bifurcation points, given the properties of the kernel $\Phi$. I ask this because, while most of TBA equations considered in the literature do not possess such a point -- e.g. sinh-Gordon TBA [2], there appear to exist a large class of kernels $\Phi$ for which the physics derived from the TBA equation share many properties with the model considered above(*). It would be important to understand if the mechanism at play is indeed the bifurcation and which conditions must be imposed on $\Phi$ in order to (not) have it. As mentioned above, the analytic properties of the kernel $\Phi$ reflect the physical properties of the underlying system, hence relating the existence of bifurcation points to specific properties of the kernel will allow for a possibly very interesting physical interpretation of the phenomenon.
2. I would like to understand the structure of the second solution.

In the specific case above, numerically I have access only to one of the solutions to (3). The behaviour (4) suggests then that the second solution might be the analytical continuation around the branching point of the first one, i.e.
\begin{equation}
 \tilde{\varepsilon}(\theta) = A(\theta) - B(\theta)\sqrt{r_c-r} + \mathcal O(r_c-r)\;.
\end{equation}
However I performed some simple numerical analysis and found that $\tilde{\varepsilon}$ does not appear to satisfy the equation (3). It might be that I am doing something wrong with this "analytic continuation" or that there are some numerical errors that I did not consider.(**) I would like to be sure that $\tilde{\epsilon}$ is a solution to (3).

3. I would like to obtain an analytic handle on $r_c$ as a function of the external parameters $\omega$ and $\gamma$.

As far as I can understand, as long as I have a solution to (5), (6) is an equation fixing the value of $r_c$. One might try to use the method of Fredholm determinant to compute the eigenvalues of the kernel $\Phi(\theta - \theta')/\left(1+e^{A(\theta')}\right)$, however as long as I cannot obtain an analytic expression for $A(\theta)$ I am going nowhere. Numerical analysis is also tricky, since the standard numerical procedures stop working when approaching $r_c$ -- I guess since the Fredholm determinant vanishes.

Given the probable impossibility of an analytic answer, I would content myself with some approximate or general result, e.g. a bound on the position of $r_c$ or a condition on the existence of such a bifurcation point.

#### Comments

(*) Without going too deep in the subject, it has to do with the fact that any function computed from the TBA equation, amongst which are the energy and the entropy of the underlying physical system, display a square root behaviour as functions of $r$. The temptation to assert that this is a consequence of a bifurcation phenomenon is great, but I would like to make sure that no other phenomenon can be the cause of this behaviour.

(**) What I did was to fit the expression (4) -- actually up to terms $\mathcal O(r_c-r)^{10}$ -- against the numerical data close to $r_c$, for various values of $\theta\in\mathbb R$. This gave me a numerical approximation of $A(\theta)$ and $B(\theta)$ -- and the subsequent terms of the expansion. I then reversed the signs in front of the square root terms and computed $$\frac{1}{\cosh(\theta)}\left[\tilde{\varepsilon}(\theta) + \intop_{\mathbb R}d\theta'\Phi(\theta - \theta')\log\left[1+e^{-\tilde{\varepsilon}(\theta')}\right]\right]\;.$$ What I find is that it is not equal to $r$.

## References

[1] A. D. Polyanin and A. V. Manzhirov, *Handbook of integral equations*, CRC Press, Boca Raton, 1998

[2] Al. Zamolodchikov *On the thermodynamic Bethe ansatz equation in the sinh-Gordon model* J. Phys. A: Math. Gen. (2006) 39 12863; arXiv: https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0005181.pdf.